Flutter StreamBuilder not updating, using smswatcher
Im using flutter package "smswatcher" to listen to incoming sms.
However, when the stream emitted an sms, the StreamBuilder did not do anything, remaining in connectionState.waiting.
home_page.dart:
import 'package:namer_app/sms_service.dart';
...
StreamBuilder(
  stream: SmsService().getSmsStream(), // Get Incoming SMS
  builder: (context, snap) {
    if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Show loading spinner
    } else if (snap.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snap.error}'); // Handle errors
    } else if (snap.hasData) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(snap.data?["sender"] ?? "NA"),
        subtitle: Text(snap.data?["body"] + dateTimeString ?? "NA"),
      );
    } else {
      return Text("No SMS available"); // Handle empty state
    }
  }
),

sms_service.dart:
This file is where all the smswatcher function stored.
// External imported packages
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:smswatcher/smswatcher.dart';

// SmsService Class
class SmsService {
  final smsWatcher = Smswatcher(); // Initialize SmsWatcher
  late StreamSubscription smsSubscription; // Handle SMS Stream

  // Start listening for incoming SMS
  Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> getSmsStream() {
    return smsWatcher.getStreamOfSMS().map((sms) {
      return {
        "sender": sms["sender"] ?? "NA",
        "body": sms["body"] ?? "NA",
        "timestamp": sms["timestamp"] ?? DateTime.now().toString(), // Add a timestamp if not present
      };
    });
  }
}

background_services.dart: I have flutter_background_service running in background to keep listening sms even when app is closed. Which is working fine.
...
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

  switch (service.runtimeType) {
    case AndroidServiceInstance: // Handle Android-specific services
      // Listen to Sms Stream
      SmsService().getSmsStream().listen((smsData) async {
        sender = smsData['sender'];
        body = smsData['body'];
        print("$sender $body");
      });
...


stream: SmsService().getSmsStream() -- don't make the Stream in the stream: parameter of a StreamBuilder.  Watch this video https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg
